# Add a field that read the last login user who makes update

Tags: sql-server, web, triggers

I tried to add a field that read the last updated user but this field read the database user “azteca”, my need here is to write the user name who login to the web application.

How I can enhance the below code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [azteca].[tr_userupdat2]

ON [azteca].[REQUEST]

AFTER UPDATE

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;
   UPDATE [azteca].[REQUEST]
   SET 
     TEXT1=USER_NAME()
    FROM INSERTED i
   WHERE i.REQUESTID = REQUEST.REQUESTID
```

Comment: Your sql server database presumably knows nothing about "The last user to login to your web app". You need to pass this information in somehow.

Comment: Also, if you need this sort of information, you'll generally find that maintaining it in the same table as the data is insufficient. I.e. user 1 runs `update table set <trash all of the data>`, then user 2 runs `update table set <innocous comment>` and all that you can find is that user 2 was the last to update the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the username in the applicationname of your connection. Then use the  `App_Name()` function in your trigger.

Comment: Thank you Peter. but how can I can set the user name in the application name of your connection

Comment: just use the `Application name` property in you connectionstring.